# Allow regex pattern to be repeated if it is comma-separated?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript regex for email addresses:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Fiddle here: https://regex101.com/r/8Z9ORb/1

Used in the .Validate plugin, this will allow `test@test.com` but not `test@test` and other bad email addresses.

But how can I allow this pattern to be repeated if comma separated? I.e, how can I allow:

- test@test.com
- test@test.com,example@exmaple.com
- test@test.com, example@exmaple.com, Nth@moreemails.com (note the spaces)

While not allowing bad emails in the CSV or a bad CSV, like:

- test@test.com,testtest.com
- test@test.com and test2@test2.com

Comment: Hint: if `/^A$/` only allows "A", then `/^A(, ?A)*$/` allows "A" followed by zero or more of ",A" with an optional space after the comma.

Comment: You're trying to use regex as a tool to do two jobs: validates email addresses, blacklists "bad" email addresses. Hint 2: don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work? But I'm no regexpert.

```
/^((([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(,|, |$))*$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/8Z9ORb/2